# Convert this SQL with left join to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

There are two tables, school and term. The school record must be shown, but the term record may not yet exist, therefore, the term may be null (thus the left join).  The left joined table must be filtered by date for the current term if it exists. Can this be done in LINQ?

```
select school.school_name, term.term_start, term.term_end 
from school
left join term on school.school_id = term.school_id and term.term_start <= '2017-10-21' and term.term_end >= '2017-10-21'
where school.active = 1 
order by school.school_name
```

UPDATE:

After some input I have a left join but if a school is missing a term I still cannot make the start and end dates show as null - the school doesn't show at all if I am missing a term, and I want the school to show in the first column.  What am I missing??  Here is the latest LinqPad code.

```
var query =  ((from sc in Schools.Where(s => s.Active == 1 )
             join t in Terms on sc.School_id equals t.School_id into ts
             from tsub in ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {name = sc.School_name, 
                         start = tsub.Term_start,
                         end = tsub.Term_end})
             .Where (o => o.start <= DateTime.Now && o.end >= DateTime.Now))
             .OrderBy( o => o.name);

query.Dump();
```

UPDATE #2

Here is a screen shot of the SQL result, and I am trying to achieve the same thing in LINQ:

[image]

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#leftouterjoin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. If you put the .Where() clause on the joined table you will get null values if there is no matching record.  Here is the LinqPad LINQ statement that works and it runs perfectly in .NET MVC.

```
var query =  ((from sc in Schools.Where(s => s.Active == 1 )
             join t in Terms.Where(x => x.Term_start <= DateTime.Now && x.Term_end >= DateTime.Now) on sc.School_id equals t.School_id into ts
             from tsub in ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {name = sc.School_name, 
                         start = tsub.Term_start,
                         end = tsub.Term_end})
             .OrderBy( o => o.name));

query.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =  from sc in school.Where(s = > s.active == 1 )
             join t in term on sc.school_id == t.school_id
             select new {name = sc.school_name, 
                         start = t.term_start,
                         end =  term.term_end}
             .Where (o => o.start <= '2017-10-21' && o.end >= '2017-10-21')
             .OrderBy( o => o.school_name)
```

Comment: barakcaf, I thought it was the right answer but after studying it for the past hour I realized that if a school did not have a term, the null value for the "start" and "end" did not show up in those columns.  I'll post my LinqPad code showing the left join but it's still not working. Appreciate the input but not quite there yet.

Comment: this is an answer to your original question (your linqPad code is almost identical to this), if you have additional requirements you should either open a new question or explain more precisely what you need to do

Comment: barakcaf, I added a screen shot of the result I am trying to achieve in Update #2. I need to be able to do a left join and retrieve all school names and if a school doesn't have a term then it returns a null, which it does nicely in SQL.  I haven't been able to duplicate this result in LINQ. Thanks for you help.